# jQuery / JSON / CodeIgniter - Form validation

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

Im trying to get starting with JSON and jQuery. I'm not a JavaScript programmer at all so I'm mixing and matching and having quite a few issues getting my code to work. I thought someone might be able to help me out.

I have a model which uses the following PHP code to check if an email address is registered with the system:

```
function is_email_available($email) {
  $this->db->select('1', FALSE);
  $this->db->where('LOWER(email)=', strtolower($email));
  $this->db->or_where('LOWER(new_email)=', strtolower($email));

  $query = $this->db->get($this->table_name);
  return $query->num_rows() == 0;
}
```

The above code is being called by my ajax controller using the following, and if it is registered returns a json true or false

```
function email_availability() {

  // Check to see if the username is available or taken
  if ( $this->users->is_email_available( $this->input->post('emailaddress'))) {
    echo json_encode(TRUE);
  } else {
    echo json_encode(FALSE);
  }

}
```

The above is called from my JS file using the following jQuery, but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

```
if(iEmail.val()) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/email_availability',
    data: 'emailaddress=' + iEmail.val(),
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    success: function(msg) {
      iEmail.next('.error').text('This Email Address is not registered');
      error = true;
    }
  });
}
```

I think my jQuery is completely off but can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is the error? in the request part or in the response? check in firebug if the request to your php page is actually sent

Comment: @gpasci - Its just returning 'TRUE' if the email address entered is not in the database

Comment: You don't need to use json_encode( true). instead you can just echo 1 or 0. Another thing do you get any error? Where? Have you tried debugging your code with firebug or the developer tools from chrome?

Comment: post console.log(msg) log inside success() callback

Comment: It says error, but the page reloads before i can check it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really check if the result was true or false.

```
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg){
                //email is available
            }
            else{
                //email is not available
            }
        }
```